# Setting Class from External SWF - Implicit Coercion

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to load in an SWF into my main file. The SWF is ColorWheel.swf, and the main file is c_test.as. Here is my code:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();   
this.addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("ColorWheel.swf"));  
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,imageLoaded);
var myClass:Class;

function imageLoaded(e:Event):Class
{
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,imageLoaded);    
   return loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("StageColorWheel") as Class;
}

myClass = imageLoaded;
var myWheel:BitmapData = new myClass();
```

This gives me an implicit coercion error where I have `myClass = imageLoaded`. I'm fairly certain this is an easy fix, but if anyone has an answer I'd much appreciate it. This was my current code before (which worked, but *everything* following loading the swf into c_test.as was included in the `imageLoaded` function.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();   
this.addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("ColorWheel.swf"));  
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,imageLoaded);
var myClass:Class;

function imageLoaded(e:Event):Class
{
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,imageLoaded);    
   myClass = loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("StageColorWheel") as Class;

   var myWheel:BitmapData = new myClass();
   //rest of code - works
}
```

Comment: Please include the exact error in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cover the why of the actual error, in the following line:

```
myClass = imageLoaded;
```

You are not calling the function because you're missing the parenthesis `()`.  It should be:

```
myClass = imageLoaded();
```

Without the parenthesis `()`, you're just assigning a reference to the function itself to the `myClass` var, which is what is causing the error because the var needs to hold a `Class` reference not a `Function` reference.

However, even if you correct that, this is not going to work right.

The `imageLoaded()` method should only run **after** the load completes (and indeed it will run when it completes because you have it as an event handler as well).

At the time you do `myClass = imageLoaded()`, the loader has not completed loading yet so your result will be different/null.

Your second way of doing it is the appropriate way to go about this.

Comment: Yes, I realized that since Flash is asynchronous, that my SWF files may not load fast enough, and that a class may be trying to be used without actually being defined. Thank you!